# Transferring radio button value into a session variable

Tags: php, session, radio-button

I am creating several forms all submitted via POST in PHP and stored in sessions. However I cannot get the radio button to store a value into the session. I am trying to store the radio button's value in the session but cannot get it display. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is a sample of the code I am using;

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="testform2.php">
<input type="radio" id="age" name="age" value="yes"/>Yes<br/>
<input type="radio" id="age" name="age" value="no"/>No<br/>
If no, please tell us your date of birth:<br/>
<textarea id="age" name="age" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Next"></br>
</form>
```

PHP: At the start of the next form (testform2.php)

```
<?php
session_start();

$age=$_POST['age'];

$_SESSION['age']=$age;

echo $_SESSION['age'];
?>
```

With this I don't get anything from the echo despite clicking on the radio button.

Comment: if you echo out `$_POST['age']` what do you get? also, theres no need to add `$age = post, then $sess = $age` .. simply do `$_SESSION['age'] = $_POST['age']`... use `checked="yes"` on the one you want to be default

Comment: Are you clicking one of the radio buttons before submitting the form?

Comment: Yes I am clicking the radio buttons before submitting and I don't get anything from the echo, that's the problem. I'll edit the initial question.

Comment: The code looks fine to me, you could try adding `print_r($_POST);` after your `session_start();` just to make sure the values are coming across as expected.

Comment: working perfect for me... kindly check out echo $_POST['age']; is getting the data

Comment: confirm one more thing, the php and the html code are in same file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure firstly you have started the session on both pages, and any other pages you use as the first line in the page (well after

You can debug by doing

```
print_r($_POST);
```

this will print everything in POST, then do the same for session. If its not in the post print then there is an issue with your form, if its in the post print but not in the session print then something is going wrong with it being set.

Comment: This will actually print_r everything in $_POST not $_SESSION :-)

Comment: Ah brilliant thank you, it wasn't the issue but it showed up my problem I'll edit the question and accept this answer. Thank you. The issue being I have a textarea after the "no" answer (if no give dob) as it's an application form, any idea on how to solve that? Thank you once again.